# What is the problem with my recurvise haskell code?

Tags: haskell, char

> Implement the password :: [Char] -> [Char] function, which is a string replaces all characters with *.

Test:

password "akacfa2" == "*******"

password "hunter1234" == "**********"

password ['a'] == ['*']

password [] == []

```
password :: [Char] -> [Char]
password [] = []
password (x: xs) = ["*" + password xs]
```

It is not working with the + sign. What can be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```hs
password :: [Char] -> [Char]
password [] = []
password (x:xs) = "*" ++ password xs
```

I guess that was your intent from the code you have provided. `String` is of type `[Char]` which is just a synonym for it. You don't need to put them in an additional `[]` because they are already a `[]` of `Char`s. In addition, the concatenation operator for `String`s is `++`.

On a side note, this is not the proper way to solve this problem, even if you are required to do it with explicit recursion and without using any helper functions.

You can make use of the fact that `String`s are lists of characters and just add characters of `*` to the list for each character you encounter in the input password. Something like the following:

```hs
password :: [Char] -> [Char]
password [] = []
password (x:xs) = '*' : password xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicit recursion, like

```
password [] = []
password (x:xs) = '*' : password xs
```

isn't needed here. You can use `map` to replace each character with a `'*'`.

```
password xs = map (\x -> '*') xs
```

Since a list is a functor, you can use `fmap` instead:

```
password xs = fmap (\x -> '*') xs
```

(`map` is just `fmap` specialized to lists.)

The `Functor` type class provides an additional method for this special case of replacing each element with the same value:

```
password xs = '*' <$ xs
```